# How to plot a subset of nodes of a networkx graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, networkx

This is code similar to my code

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib notebook
import pandas as pd

data={"A":["T1","T2","tom","adi","matan","tali","pimpunzu","jack","arzu"],
      "B":["end","end","T1","T1","T1","T2","T2","matan","matan"]}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,source='A',target='B', edge_attr=None, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', ax=ax)
```

i like to plot part of the graph for example ,i like to plot just `["T1","matan","jack","arzu"]`

that what i like to get

```
data={"A":["jack","arzu","matan"],
      "B":["matan","matan","T1"]}

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,source='A',target='B', edge_attr=None, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', ax=ax)
```

**can i put list of what i like to plot?
or maybe can i write the nodes i like to plot between them?**

Answer (score 8):

You can generate a [`nx.subgraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html) from a list of nodes, and draw as you're doing above:

```
H = nx.subgraph(G, ["T1","matan","jack","arzu"])
nx.draw(H, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold', node_color='lightblue', node_size=500)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to plot a subgraph of your original graph. To do this, you can use the [`networkx.Graph.subgraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html#networkx-graph-subgraph) method:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

# Build a graph using a pd.DataFrame
data = {"A": ["T1","T2","tom","adi","matan","tali","pimpunzu","jack","arzu"],
        "B": ["end","end","T1","T1","T1","T2","T2","matan","matan"]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='A', target='B', edge_attr=None,
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph())

# Build subgraph containing a subset of the nodes, and edges between those nodes
subgraph = G.subgraph(["T1","matan","jack","arzu"])
```

Now you just need to simply plot your new graph using the same function from matplotlib you have already used.